# Manejar distintos tipos de excepciones en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quería saber si podeis ayudarme. Tengo una pequeña duda sobre try except.

```
try:
  for i in ls ():
       if filename == i:
           f =open (filename,'w')....
except FileExistsError or FileNotFoundError :
if FileExistsError...
```

Lo que no entiendo es:
1) En except, ¿puedo poner dos nombres de errores con los operadores lógicos and y or?
2) En except, como puedo poner para que ejecute dos cosas dependiendo de si es FileNotFoundError o FileExistsError. 
Por ejemplo uno envía  un mensaje con un código de error 2 y el otro un 3.

No se si mas o menos me he explicado bien. Espero que podais ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Los debes poner en forma secuencial de esta forma:

```
import os
import errno

try:

  os.mkdir('G:\folderPath')
  a = b

except OSError as e:
  print('OSError dice :' + str(e))
except Exception as e:
  print('Exception dice :' + str(e))
except (SystemError, KeyboardInterrupt):
  print('SystemError dice : ' + str(e))
```

Si comentas la línea  `a = b` el error te dirá:

```
FileExistsError dice :[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado:...
```

Si comentas la línea  `os.mkdir('G:\folderPath')`  el error te dirá:

```
Exception dice :name 'b' is not defined
```

Y así, puedes incorporar todos los tipos de errores que creas que puedan suceder en la rutina. Más información aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html